# Green tint to wallpaper - Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, images, wallpaper

I'm trying to set a new wallpaper image in Linux Mint 19 and the image is given a strong green hue rather than appearing as it actually is.  See attached image, very self-explanatory.  I'm looking for a solution to stop my wallpaper from automatically getting this green tint.

[image: wallpaper image hue issue]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

The image was using Adobe RGB colour profile, which apparently is not handled properly.  I converted to sRGB and there is no issue.

Comment: Add some explanation and the procedure that you've followed.